# Regexmatch not matching Google Sheets and show matches

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, unique, matching

I'm trying to do a clean up of the repeated questions, doing  an split of number from the questions. My problems comes when after I split the cell with the number and text of the question. I do create a formula to show only once the number if is reapeated and made a list of the no repeated numbers, after this I tried to do a regexmatch of this cleaned numbers with this formula `REGEXMATCH($A$2:$A$15, C3)` but it looks with repeated numbers have a problem, also after the repeated also shows error below will be the screenshot.
Second problem if the regexmatch is true will appear the question that matches with that number also is not printing I used this formula `=IF(D2=TRUE, $A$2:$A$15)`. It works when there is not repeated numbers but the most of the time the data that I worked is like in the screenshot.

[image: REGEXMATCH NOT WORKING]

[image: Show matching not working]

Extra:
Now I have this problem also with some of them
[image]

Comment: My apologies as your post is quite unclear. Can you share an expected result you want to achieve?  Also, where's the error you've mentioned after the repeated number?   Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I hope now is more clear, the error appears in D2, is this one. `Error
An array value could not be found.` @irvin-jay-g thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you just want a unique list of what is in A2:A15.

If that is correct, delete *everything* from Column B, Column C, Column D and Column E. You should have data in only Column A.

In cell B2, place this formula:

`=UNIQUE(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""))`

You can place the formula anywhere in the sheet. It does not have to be in cell B2.

**ADDENDUM** (based on additional information in comments and changes to original post)

Still delete everything Col B, C, D and E.

Place the following formula in B2:

`=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("*"&UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(A2:A,A2:A<>""),"\d+"))&"*",A2:A,1,FALSE))`

Comment: I added some colors in the first Image actually what you send helpme a lot but somethimes I have like multiples questions 7 and I just need one from them. That's why I split it in numbers because the text is different.

Comment: Try the new formula I just added at the bottom of my post above.

Comment: Yep that's exactly what I need it thanks

Comment: Happy to hear it. Much easier than using so many "helper columns."

Comment: I updated with your new formula some error in a few rows that I have, if you could help me with that will be the awesome is the last thing I promise.

Comment: Please provide a link to the spreadsheet here and explain the problem you are having. That will be the easiest way for me to help you.

Comment: Copy and paste the bottom formula from my post again. (I made a small update for you.)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242023/discussion-between-erik-tyler-and-eduardomaker).

Comment: Hey I was using the formula but it don't work with 15.1 numbers, this is the formula that I'm using `=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(REGEXEXTRACT(FILTER(A2:A1000,A2:A1000<>""),"\d+"))&"*",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A1000,"\d+.+$"),1,FALSE))`